# Google Maps API Zoom to fit KmlLayer

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am currently using Google Maps API for Android. I'm trying to make a zoom on the KmlLayer I added to the map but I can't figure out how.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml?hl=en

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative to the problem. I can't zoom the map to fit with the layer but I can zoom to a specific location.

This code read the KmlLayer and get a KmlPoint object. Then you can zoom to its location:

```
for (KmlContainer c : layer.getContainers()) {
    for (KmlPlacemark p : c.getPlacemarks()){
        KmlGeometry g = p.getGeometry();
        if(g.getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
            LatLng point = (LatLng) g.getGeometryObject();
            Log.e("POINT", point.latitude+" "+point.longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help :-)